# What is the recommended way to autostart a Postgres cluster using a nonstandard data directory?

Tags: postgresql, linux

I am running PostgreSQL 9.5 on Linux Mint 18.

- At installation, apt creates a cluster in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`.
- Environment settings (`postgresql.conf`, `pg_hba.conf`, `pg_ident.conf`) are stored in `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main`.
- `postgresql.conf` sets data directory to `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`.

I have a root partition that is deliberately small, and want to have my cluster on a larger data partition. I ran `initdb` in `/data/pg_data`. I am able to start and stop this cluster manually using `pg_ctl`. My question is, how do I start Postgres using this cluster at system startup?

I read [17.3 Starting the Database Server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/server-start.html) in the Postgres docs. That page describes (a) setting the `PGDATA` environment variable, or (b) having the server start the postgres daemon at boot time.

## Using PGDATA

I tried to accomplish this by adding the following line to `/etc/environment`:

```
PGDATA="/data/pg_data"
```

I then restarted. Postgres started, but is still using default data directory. `echo $PGDATA` indicates environment variable was set, and if I stop running cluster, `pg_ctl start` without data directory specified does start desired cluster. But it's not handling it at boot time.

## Using init scripts

I can't figure this one out.

The docs say:

> Different systems have different conventions for starting up daemons at boot time. Many systems have a file /etc/rc.local or /etc/rc.d/rc.local. Others use init.d or rc.d directories.
>
> ---
>
> - On Linux systems either add
>
>   ```
>   /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -l logfile -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
>   ```
>
>   to /etc/rc.d/rc.local or /etc/rc.local or look at the file contrib/start-scripts/linux in the PostgreSQL source distribution.

Linux Mint uses `init.d` folder. I found a `postgresql` file in there and opened it. It is a 60 line bash script. The first few lines are:

```
# Setting environment variables for the postmaster here does not work; please
# set them in /etc/postgresql/<version>/<cluster>/environment instead.

[ -r /usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions ] || exit 0

. /usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions
```

So, first I look in `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/environment`. That file is empty except for comments. The first line says `# environment variables for postmaster process`. Is something supposed to go in here that points to my desired data directory?

The file includes `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions`. That is a 112 line file that clearly points to `/etc/postgresql/<version number>` and attempts to start all clusters that it finds there. It also clearly references `postgresql.conf`. So it seems that this is how the default cluster is being started, but it is not clear to me that this can or should be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are You using the official packages<sup>[1]</sup>, supported by the PGDG?

You can do 2 things:

1. edit the startup script file (or make a simbolic link) pointing to the new directory.
2. Edit the `/etc/postgresql/[version]/[cluster]/pg_ctl.conf` to point to the new directory;

Please, take a look a documentation from debian website<sup>[2]</sup> to see more details.

**EDIT:** Looks like what you are looking for it's the `pg_createcluster`<sup>[3]</sup> utility.

Hope it helps!

References:

1. http://apt.postgresql.org
2. https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql
3. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html

Comment: I am using Ubuntu repositories, not apt.postgres.org. Debian documentation (link 2) looks promising. I will try that and report back.

Comment: This set me on the right track, but following the conventions of SE, I would ask that you elaborate on the answer rather than just link to the solution. I ended up using link 2, as well as the documentation for [pg_createcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html) discussed therein, to find the right solution. I have blogged it [here](http://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2016/10/10/setting-a-custom-data-directory-for-a-new-postresql-installation-on-linux/). I would edit your answer myself, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: nice post @LeeHachadoorian!  I will edit the post. Remember to use the packages from the PGDG repo.